# CodeIgniter does not load view - loads only white screen when view exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am only getting a white screen for the following code when i go to localhost/Home/Careers

NOTE: When I have the view_name.php file in the views folder, i get white screen of death.  If I delete view_name.php from the views folder, I see the "test" and a "cannot find file error".

Any ideas?

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function Careers()
    {
            echo "test";
            $this->load->view('view_name');
    }

}
```

Comment: I see you have named `controllers/home.php` try `controllers/Home.php` for file name first letter must be upper case only same with class and also try `http://localhost/index.php/home/Careers` make sure you have set your base url in config.php

Comment: how to you call the view? any php in the view?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-a-view

Comment: I followed those exact instructions, and its not working.  There are other views that work, just not this new one.

Comment: There is no php in the file @Vickel

Comment: Once I change the "echo "test";" to a $this->load->view('view_name');    i get white screen.

Comment: $this->load->view('view_name'); ... and yes, there is a view_name.php file in the views directory.

Comment: updated the original question to be more clear

Comment: right click on browser and check ***view page source***.you can easily find what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are not mentioning "projectname" before controller name in browser.

Please try in browser with localhost/Project_name/Home/Careers

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!

File permissions were wrong !   I did a chmod 755 on the php file and it works perfectly.

Chmod 755 filename.php

Answer (score 0):

```
> > **In Controller:**

       <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access
      allowed');

    class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function Careers()
    {
          $data['test']="test";
          $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
    }

    }

> >  In **view_name.php:**

    <?php
    echo $test; 
    ?>
```